# Indentation error in python 2.7 shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

Hi when i am copying this complete snippet in python shell it is giving indentation error

---

```
import heapq    
dict = {4: 'four', 1 : 'one', 3: 'third', 2: 'two', 5:'five'}
h = []
for value in dict:
    heapq.heappush(h, value)

for i in range(len(h)):
    a = heapq.heappop(h)
    print a,'  ',dict[a]
```

---

but if i copy first block

```
import heapq    
dict = {4: 'four', 1 : 'one', 3: 'third', 2: 'two', 5:'five'}
h = []
for value in dict:
    heapq.heappush(h, value)
```

hit enter and then copy second block

```
for i in range(len(h)):
    a = heapq.heappop(h)
    print a,'  ',dict[a]
```

hit enter and it works fine

please guide where indentation problem is happening.

Comment: You might have mess up with space and tabs.

Comment: normally copy and pasting is troublesome in the python shell. consider pasting the code in an editor first and doing any cleanup and then pasting again.

Comment: I suggest using ipython

Comment: I second ipython and its "magic" command `%cpaste`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy-paste into Python interactive interpreter and indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712389/copy-paste-into-python-interactive-interpreter-and-indentation)

Comment: I think  a tab between two for statement blocks was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you paste in the sequence:

```
for value in dict:
    heapq.heappush(h, value)

for i in range(len(h)):
```

Auto-indentation results in:

```
for value in dict:
    heapq.heappush(h, value)

    for i in range(len(h)):
```

Hence your problem.